# Difference between money words

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference, word-in-context

There a couple of words concerning payment. In which case which word do we use to pay?

- Fine
- Fee
- Fare
- Tip
- Bribery
- Commision
- Salary
- Wage
- Loan
- Charge
- Tax

As far as I know. 'Tip' is for those who serve you in a restaurant, 'Loan' is something a bank gives you, 'Salary' is what we give at work to the workers, 'Bribery' is when we want to hood a crime. What about the others?

Comment: None of them means "to pay".

Comment: They are pretty straightforward and distinct terms - have you consulted a dictionary?

Comment: @Mike Yes, but it's not exactly said where you use a commision and where you use a fee for instance. Or what the difference between a charge and fine is.

Comment: A *charge* is any kind of request for payment. I can't really go through them all. As @mike says, they are all dictionary words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fine

Money paid as a result of punishment given because of a mistake/crime.

> Fee

Money paid for a service, like in educational and governmental institutions.

> Fare

Money paid to the owner of the vehicle which you used for locomotion.

> Tip

Money paid as a result of satisfaction received from a service. Note that this is above the bill (or fee) for the actual service.

> Bribery

Money paid to influence an official (usually someone holding an office of power) to do something out of the book.

> Commision

Money earned by promoting or generating sales for a product/service owned by someone else.

> Salary

Money given by the employer to his/her employee for discharging his/her duties as laid out in the contract letter. This is mostly paid out on a monthly basis.

> Wage

Same as salary, but paid on a daily basis.

> Loan

Money given to someone in need, and taken back along with specified interest in a specified amount of time.

> Charge

Money asked by a service provider in exchange for his/her services. Note that 'fee' is the term used by the service receiver.

> Tax

Money paid by citizens/businesses to the Government.

Comment: There's a difference between salary and wages, plus cultural differences. In the US, a salary is a fixed amount paid monthly, regardless of the number of hours you have worked (i.e. no paid overtime). In the UK, salary tends used for white-collar workers, while wages is used more for manual laborers.